# Can't seem to select multiple circles at the same time

Tags: pygame

I'm working on this game called abalone and I can't seem to select multiple of the coins at the same time. If I select one coin and click on another the selection resets and only selects the latest coin selected.

I've attached my code below.

```
            import pygame
            from pygame.locals import *
            import sys
            import random
            import math 
            pygame.init()
            win=pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600))
            colorname=(128,128,128)
            display_width=1000
            display_height=600
            red=(255,0,0)
            blue=(0,0,255)
            green=(0,255,0)
            pygame.display.set_caption(("Abalone"))
            pygame.draw.polygon(win,(0,0,0),[(650,0),(1000,0),(1000,600),(600,600)],0)
            pygame.display.update()
            def abalone_board():
                pygame.draw.polygon(win, (165,42,42),[(150,20),(450,20),(600,300),(450,580),(150,580),(0,300)],0)
                pygame.draw.polygon(win, (0,0,0),[(150,20),(450,20),(600,300),(450,580),(150,580),(0,300)],5)
                for i in range(172,434,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(237, 187, 153),(i, 60),30,0)
                for i in range(140,499,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(237, 187, 153),(i, 120),30,0)
                for i in range(110,499,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(237, 187, 153),(i, 180),30,0)
                for i in range(80,563,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(237, 187, 153),(i, 240),30,0)
                for i in range(50,563,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(237, 187, 153),(i, 300),30,0)
                for i in range(80,563,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(237, 187, 153),(i, 360),30,0)
                for i in range(110,499,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(237, 187, 153),(i, 420),30,0)
                for i in range(140,499,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(237, 187, 153),(i, 480),30,0)
                for i in range(172,434,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(237, 187, 153),(i, 540),30,0)
                for i in range(172,434,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,0),(i, 60),30,2)
                for i in range(140,499,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,0),(i, 120),30,2)
                for i in range(110,499,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,0),(i, 180),30,2)
                for i in range(80,563,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,0),(i, 240),30,2)
                for i in range(50,563,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,0),(i, 300),30,2)
                for i in range(80,563,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,0),(i, 360),30,2)
                for i in range(110,499,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,0),(i, 420),30,2)
                for i in range(140,499,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,0),(i, 480),30,2)
                for i in range(172,434,64):
                          pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,0),(i, 540),30,2)
                return abalone_board
            def leader_board():
                pygame.draw.polygon(win,(192,192,192),[(650,0),(1000,0),(1000,600),(650,600)],0)
                pygame.draw.polygon(win,(0,0,0),[(650,5),(995,5),(995,595),(650,595)],10)
                return leader_board
            def marble_red():
                pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(172, 60),23,0)
                return marble_red
            def ini_pos_red():
                r1=pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(428,540),23,0)
                r2=pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(364,540),23,0)
                r3=pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(300,540),23,0)
                r4=pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(236,540),23,0)
                r5=pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(172,540),23,0)
                r6=pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(460,480),23,0)
                r7=pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(396,480),23,0)
                r8=pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(332,480),23,0)
                r9=pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(268,480),23,0)
                r10=pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(204,480),23,0)
                r11=pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(140,480),23,0)
                r12=pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(238,420),23,0)
                r13=pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(302,420),23,0)
                r14=pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(366,420),23,0)
                return ini_pos_red
            def ini_pos_blue():
                b1=pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,255),(428,60),23,0)
                b2=pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,255),(364,60),23,0)
                b3=pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,255),(300,60),23,0)
                b4=pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,255),(236,60),23,0)
                b5=pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,255),(172,60),23,0)
                b6=pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,255),(460,120),23,0)
                b7=pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,255),(396,120),23,0)
                b8=pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,255),(332,120),23,0)
                b9=pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,255),(268,120),23,0)
                b10=pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,255),(204,120),23,0)
                b11=pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,255),(140,120),23,0)
                b12=pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,255),(238,180),23,0)
                b13=pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,255),(302,180),23,0)
                b14=pygame.draw.circle(win,(0,0,255),(366,180),23,0)
                return ini_pos_blue
            def text_object(text,color,size):
                if size=='small':
                    textSurface=smallfont.render(text,True,color)
                if size=='medium':
                    textSurface=medfont.render(text,True,color)
                if size=='large':
                    textSurface=largefont.render(text,True,color)
                return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
            def message_to_screen(msg,color,y_displace=0,size='small'):
                textSurf,textRect=text_object(msg,color,size)
                textRect.center=(display_width/2),(display_height/2)+y_displace
                win.blit(textSurf,textRect)
            def game_intro():
                intro = True
                while intro:
                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                            pygame.quit()
                            quit()
                    if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key==pygame.K_c:
                            intro = False
                        if event.key==pygame.K_q:
                            pygame.quit()
                            sys.exit(0)
                            quit()    
                    win.fill((255,255,255))
                    message_to_screen("Welcome to Abalone",red,-100,"large")
                    message_to_screen("The Objective of this game is to push your opponents marbles outside",blue,-30)
                    message_to_screen("At a trun , you can either move one , two or three marbles",blue,10)
                    message_to_screen("you can push your opponent's marbles that are in a line ",blue,50)
                    message_to_screen("to their own with an in-line move only.you can only push ",blue,90)
                    message_to_screen("if the pushing line has more marbles than the pushed line ",blue,130)
                    message_to_screen("Press C to play and Q to exit ",green,200)
                    pygame.display.update()        
            x1=random.randint(0,61)
            marble_red()    
            position=[(172,60),(236,60),(300,60),(364,60),(428,60),(140,120),(204,120),(268,120),(332,120),
                      (396,120),(460,120),(110,180),(174,180),(238,180),(302,180),(366,180),(430,180),
                      (494,180),(80,240),(144,240),(208,240),(272,240),(336,240),(400,240),(464,240),
                      (528,240),(50,300),(114,300),(178,300),(242,300),(306,300),(370,300),(434,300),
                      (498,300),(562,300),(80,360),(144,360),(208,360),(272,360),(336,360),(400,360),
                      (464,360),(528,360),(110,420),(174,420),(238,420),(302,420),(366,420),(430,420),
                      (494,420),(140,480),(204,480),(268,480),(332,480),(396,480),(460,480),(172,540),
                      (236,540),(300,540),(300,540),(364,540),(428,540)]
            smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
            medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 50)
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 80)
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 68)
            text = font.render("ABALONE", True, (0, 0, 0))
            grid=[
                  [1,1,1,1,1],
                 [1,1,1,1,1,1],
                [0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,2,2,2,0,0],
                 [2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  [2,2,2,2,2]
                ] 
            class circle:
                def __init__(self, pos, colour):
                    self.pos = pos
                    self.colour = colour
                    self.radius = 23       
            def circle_clicked_on(pos, circles):
                for c in circles:
                    if distance(c.pos, pos) < c.radius:
                        return c
                return False 
            def distance(p1,p2):
                return math.sqrt(((p1[0] - p2[0])**2) + ((p1[1] - p2[1])**2))
            circles=[]
            for p in position:
                circles.append(circle(p, red))
            posn=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            def gameloop():
                red=(255,0,0)
                run=True
                current_circle = False
                while run:
                    pygame.time.delay(250)
                    ms=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                            run=False
                        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                                run = False
                        elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
                            current_circle = circle_clicked_on(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), circles)
                    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
                    win.fill((colorname))
                    abalone_board()
                    leader_board()
                    ini_pos_red()
                    ini_pos_blue()
                    if current_circle and win.get_at(current_circle.pos)==red :
                        pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,255,255),current_circle.pos,23,5)
                    win.blit(text, (659,0))
                    pygame.display.update()
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)
            game_intro()
            gameloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You store the selected coin in the variable `current_circle`, and every time the player clicks on a coin the variable is overwritten.

You could use a list instead, something like this:

```
...
run=True
clicked_circles = [] # use a list here
while run:
...
        elif event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
            # store clicked coins in a list
            current_circle = circle_clicked_on(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), circles)
            if current_circle and win.get_at(current_circle.pos)==red:
                clicked_circles.append(current_circle)
    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    win.fill((colorname))
    abalone_board()
    leader_board()
    ini_pos_red()
    ini_pos_blue()
    for current_circle in clicked_circles: # iterate over list
        pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,255,255),current_circle.pos,23,5)
...
```

Comment: is there a way to restrict the selection to just three coins at a time. I tried using variable count=0 and then incremented it everytime a selection is made. but then I also had to reset the value of count to zero. so what happens is everytime it's over it starts all over again. any suggestions for this